# Magento 2.3.2 - Products with same position in category sorting issue?

Tags: products, product-list, category-products, magento2.3.2, sort-by-position

We recently migrated a store from M1 to M2.3 - the site has thousands of products and hundreds of categories.

Within each category, there are several instances whereby more than one product has the same position value. Why this is? I don't know.

Anyway, this category is sorted by "Best Value", which as I understand it, is position followed by entity_id (sorted in ascending order). So basically if 2 products have the same position, the one with the lowest ID is displayed first.

In Magento 2 though, it appears that it's the product with the highest ID first. So the category now has a big chunk of products listed backwards.

For example:

Magento 1

1) ID: 25, Pos: 0

2) ID: 53, Pos: 1

3) ID: 18, Pos: 2

4) ID: 25, Pos: 2

5) ID: 88, Pos: 2

In Magento 2, this is showing like this:

1) ID: 25, Pos: 0

2) ID: 53, Pos: 1

3) ID: 88, Pos: 2

4) ID: 25, Pos: 2

5) ID: 18, Pos: 2

So Product 18 and 88 have swapped places.

As you can imagine, this is creating difference between magento 1.9 & Magento 2.3 website about their positioning. It'll take a lot of manual work to re-assign the positions and prevent duplication.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: vinod kumar did you get any soluthion

Comment: I didn't get any solution